# semantic ui dropdown when hover

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, semantic-ui

everybody, I'm trying the first example in 
https://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html
it should work when hovering it any idea I'm not getting any error in the console but the dropdown not working not even when I click nothing happens 
may this happens because I'm using semantic-ui CDN ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Dev College</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css" />

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui text menu">
            <div class="item">
            <img src="default.png">
            </div>
            <a class="browse item">
            Browse Courses
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="ui right dropdown item">
            More
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="item">Applications</div>
                <div class="item">International Students</div>
                <div class="item">Scholarships</div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui flowing basic admission popup">
            <div class="ui three column relaxed divided grid">
            <div class="column">
                <h4 class="ui header">Business</h4>
                <div class="ui link list">
                <a class="item">Design &amp; Urban Ecologies</a>
                <a class="item">Fashion Design</a>
                <a class="item">Fine Art</a>
                <a class="item">Strategic Design</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h4 class="ui header">Liberal Arts</h4>
                <div class="ui link list">
                <a class="item">Anthropology</a>
                <a class="item">Economics</a>
                <a class="item">Media Studies</a>
                <a class="item">Philosophy</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h4 class="ui header">Social Sciences</h4>
                <div class="ui link list">
                <a class="item">Food Studies</a>
                <a class="item">Journalism</a>
                <a class="item">Non Profit Management</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code doesn't include any javascript like the other examples on the same page. If you want the dropdowns to work look into the dropdown documentation under the usage tab which talks more about coupling the dropdowns inside the menu. [Dropdowns](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/usage#active). And the CDN is fine.